# EC2 r3.8xlarge EBS storage limit

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

We have a r3.8xlarge SQL 2014 instance. We have attached 2 EBS volumes (each of 5 TB) to this instance.

We need another 5TB volume that we plan to attach to this SQL instance.

Is there a limit on how many EBS volumes can be attached or total EBS storage limit that can be attached to an EC2 e.g. not exceeding 15 TB or some best practice?

For our scenario, we expect the instance to be running only against one EBS volume at a given time.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create EBS General Purpose SSD (gp2), Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1), Throughput Optimized HDD (st1), and Cold HDD (sc1) volumes up to 16 TiB in size.

Linux:
Attaching more than 40 volumes to a Linux instance is supported on a best effort basis only and is not guaranteed.

Windows: Attaching more than the following volumes to a Windows instance is supported on a best effort basis only and is not guaranteed.

```
Driver      Volume Limit
AWS PV      26
Citrix PV   26
Red Hat PV  17
```

AWS do not recommend that you give a Windows instance more than 26 volumes with AWS PV or Citrix PV drivers, as it is likely to cause performance issues.